# typescript error on importing fuse.js library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting the typescript error every-time time to compile the code. the issues in fuse.js library and it throws an error `Module '"../../../../Users/moinahmed/react-icon-emoji-picker/node_modules/fuse.js/dist/fuse"' has no exported member 'FuseResult'.`

I have tried everything but could not solve this issue, the localhost starts running for a few seconds and then the app crashes and throws this error
[image]

Comment: Can you please show me your import code?

Comment: You probably don't want to import from `../node_modules` directly. Does changing that to `import Fuse, { FuseResult } from 'fuse'` help at all?

Comment: I tried import` Fuse, { FuseResult } from 'fuse.js'`. it throws typescript error

Answer (score 1):

`FuseResult` isn't directly exported from *fuse.js*,

The remedy is to use `type FuseResult<T> = Fuse.FuseResult<T>;` to alias `FuseResult` to `Fuse.FuseResult`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAMQK4GcCmcD0AqOAaOAb0VTQCU0UkAbeAXzm0zgDMoIQ4AiF0gOgBWKLgG4AsAChJMAJ5gMMADwAVAHxwAvCXR9k6ClVorVIoA)

> You can also use `Fuse.FuseResult` everywhere, but since you wanted to directly import I am assuming you don't want to rewrite this every time.